# "un"toggling a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery's .toggle method to create a menu that opens and closes when a div is clicked. Here is my code:

```
$(".header").toggle(function() {
        $(this).find(".parent").fadeIn("fast"); 
        $(this).css("background-color","red");         
    }, function() {
        $(this).find(".parent").fadeOut("fast"); 
        $(this).css("background-color","white");    
}); 

$(document).click(function() {
      $('.parent').fadeOut("fast");
     $(".header").css("background-color","white");

});

$(".parent").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bmcmahen/X9S5C/8/

This works well until I click outside of the pop-up menu to close it, and then try to click on the menu button again. It then requires a double click. What I need to be able to do is to untoggle the click on the div from the $(document).click function. Any idea on how I'd do this?

Comment: I generally never use toggle, instead I use one 'click' listener and rely on the 'div in questions' current state using `.is(':hidden')`

Comment: I was thinking of doing something similar -- I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', function() {
    $(".header .parent").not(':hidden').closest('.header').click();   
});
```

This will close ALL pop-up menus, not just the latest one opened.

Leave everything else as it is. No need to use `.data()` or a className.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brVXC/)

Comment: Ah.. this does seem more simple. Thanks. And yes, it closes all of the opened divs. To translate this to english: when the document is clicked, it looks for all elements with class .parent that are not hidden, finds the next-preceding .header class, and clicks it. This fires the toggle option, resetting it. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

The problem on your code is, you will need to click twice to get the `toggle` function to be continued again. So when you clicked on document then you will need to click twice on header.

I have tried to solved your problem. You can add `Active` class whichever you clicked and when you click on document then `trigger` the `active header`. See [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/X9S5C/9/)

Just replace with this code then it should work.

```
$(".header").toggle(function() {
    $(this).addClass('Active').siblings().removeClass('Active');
   $(this).find(".parent").fadeIn("fast"); 
$(this).css("background-color","red");         
}, function() {
   $(this).find(".parent").fadeOut("fast"); 
 $(this).css("background-color","white");    
}); 

$(document).click(function() {
      //$('.parent').fadeOut("fast");
     //$(".header").css("background-color","white");
    $(".header.Active").trigger('click');

});

$(".parent").click(function(event){
   event.stopPropagation(); 
}); 

$("#search").keyup(function(){
var query = $("#search").val(); 
  $("#results").append(query+"<br>"); 

});
```

​

Comment: This did it. Nice. It also removes the class from siblings too, making it more robust. Thanks!

Comment: But what if two or more pop-up menus are showing when the document is clicked? Surely you want them all to be hidden. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation very close to user1193749's but uses `jQuery().data()` to keep track of even/odd clicks:

http://jsfiddle.net/5E6VP/